# How to loop in a range of Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to render the data from a Google Spreadsheets with Express and after placing the range of the cells to render and loop into it, I have a error: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client."

The spreadsheet has 3 rows and 6 columns and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as the error is persistent and I cannot get rid of it of anyway.

My code:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const {google} = require('googleapis');
 const keys = require('../credentials.json');

 const {
   google
  } = require('googleapis');
  const keys = require('../credentials.json');

  /* GET portfolio page. */
  router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  const client = new google.auth.JWT(
  keys.client_email,
  null,
  keys.private_key,
   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
  );

  client.authorize(function (err) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     return;
     } else {
       console.log('Connected');
       gsrun(client);
     }
    });

     async function gsrun(cl) {
     const gsapi = google.sheets({
     version: 'v4',
     auth: cl
    });

     const optPort1 = {
     spreadsheetId: '1W1OKGmGU6Io-1FhWjZLyPkGZz9Ky829zurAzcwmXiHg',
     range: ['Portfolio Page!A4:F6']
   };


   let spreadvals1 = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(optPort1);


   console.log(spreadvals1.data.values);


    const cols1 = spreadvals1.data.values || [];

    const colsdata = cols1.map((element) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    res.render('portfolio', {
       headlinePortfolio: element[0],
       subheadlinePortfolio: element[1],
       image1: element[3],
       client: element[4],
       campaign: element[5]
     })
   });
 }
 });

  module.exports = router;
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
   <div class="page-header">
   <div class="text-headline">
       <div class="salutation">{{headlinePortfolio}}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-subheadline">
       <div class="descr">{{subheadlinePortfolio}}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="port-row">         
       <ul class="flex-container-port">
           <li class="flex-item-img-mob">
              <img src="{{image1}}" alt="header-image" />
           </li>
           <li class="flex-item-img-desktop">
             <img class="img-port" src="{{image2}}" alt="header-image" />
           </li>
           <li class="flex-item-descr">
              <p class="bg-text">{{client1}}</p>
              <p class="descr-text">{{campaign1}}</p>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
```

So, some dummy data will be:

```
   Name Age Year
   John 21  5
   Paul 22  6
   Mark 23  7
   Maggie 24 8
   Beth 25  9
   Patsy26  10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem it is in this line:

```
const colsdata = cols1.map((element) => {
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');

res.render('portfolio', {
   headlinePortfolio: element[0],
   subheadlinePortfolio: element[1],
   image1: element[3],
   client: element[4],
   campaign: element[5]
 })
```

})

You **cannot **render** more than once**. Render calls the method **res.send()** which sends data to the front-end. So what is happening is: You are sending (res.send()) several times (because res.render is inside the map) thus the error.

For you prevent the render to send the data you have to provide a callback like so:

```
res.render('portfolio', {
   headlinePortfolio: element[0],
   subheadlinePortfolio: element[1],
   image1: element[3],
   client: element[4],
   campaign: element[5]
 }, ()=>console.log(`template created do something`))
```

and the when you are ready to send everything you will just try to send everything in one go with: `res.send(data)`

Also you `router.get` has to be **async** in order to the **await** keyword work.

**More update:**

You have updated your answer therefore this is a more dumb down approach of everything that I had shared above.

You are trying to create **one** template but the problem is that you are creating **multiple** templates because you are using a **function** inside a **loop**. What you should be doing is to remove the function from the loop.

*Unfortunately I cannot teach exactly how to achieve what you want to achieve. I will reproduce a minimum output so you can work from there:*

*Note: In order to simplify, everything that is not here should stay the same.*

```
 /* GET portfolio page. */
  router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {

     ...
    const cols1 = spreadvals1.data.values || [];


  // I have removed the .map fn. You should do the same

    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.render('portfolio', {
       headlinePortfolio: cols[0][0], //row 1 - elem (col) 1
       subheadlinePortfolio:cols[0][1], //row 1 - elem  (col) 2
       image1: cols[0][3], //row 1 - elem (col) 4
       client: cols[0][4],//row 1 - elem (col) 5
       campaign: cols[0][5], // row 1 - elem (col) 6
     })

 }
 });

  module.exports = router;
```

With the example above you will have no errors and it will only get the first row. If you want the next rows you will have to increase for *row[1]*, *row[2]*, *row[3]* and so forth...
If you wanna multiple (separated) templates from different rows you will have to dig deeper and understand what I am saying about callbacks and implement it with map.

Comment: Hi iwaduarte, I'm new to express and not sure how can I accomplish what you said. If you could please give me some example, that will be great. I'm twisting my head over this now hehe. Cheers

Comment: Hi Fernando. What exactly you are trying to achieve? Why are you looping several times?

Comment: I want to display the content of the Google Spreadsheets in the page and I'm looping through the range. So, I'm using Handlebars which I just learned how to use it yesterday and each element that is rendering, will be the content of the handlebar shortcode.

Comment: The element[0], element[1], etc, is referencing the cells of the spreadsheet as an array.

Comment: Yeah but the map it is also referencing the rows. 
So row 1 has element[0], element[1], element[2]
row 2 has element[0]. element[1], element[2].

The map is creating several templates.

Comment: I'm not sure how should I proceed if it's creating different templates. I'm really stuck on this issue... :/

Comment: Please print screen a simplified dummy excel files with the columns and rows. And also the portfolio html page. So I could help with you with a definite answer.

Comment: Ok, shall we move to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224925/discussion-between-fernando-fas-and-iwaduarte).

Comment: Hi iwaduarte, I have a interview tomorrow about it. If you could help me with that will be great.

Comment: Thank yo and that is really useful.